# Locating Class Property by Name from an String

Tags: c#

I want to be able to determine which class property has been selected based on a string input by the user, where the string is the name of one of the class properties.

For example

```
string userInput = "PropertyName";
string newValue = "some value";
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.PropertyName = newValue;
```

But I do not know how to locate Properties of a custom class by Name in this way.

Can anyone suggest the most concise way of achieving this please.

Comment: You can use Reflection, but you should probably rethink the design. Maybe make an indexer instead.

Comment: Users don't select class properties.  Be careful not to mixup UI design decisions with code design decisions.  Key Value Pairs such as a `Dictionary<>` can be used to select an item based on string input from a console.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The exception of course are dev tools where you might want to deal with class members by name

Answer (score 2):

Use reflections:

```
var prop = c.GetType().GetProperty(userInput,BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
{
    prop.SetValue(c,newValue,null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am getting the compile error "No overload for SetValue takes 2 arguments".  Please advise.

Comment: Ah, ok. This method is new in .NET 4.5. Prior that you have to use the SetValue method with 3 Parameters. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link to Setting a Property by Reflection

I was able to use the following to achieve my objectives

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = c.GetType().GetProperty(userInput);
propertyInfo.SetValue(c, Convert.ChangeType(newValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```